# How can concat nested div tag in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, erb

I try to concat nested div tag in rails.

```
foo = ''
foo.concat content_tag :div do 
  label_tag 'bar' 
end
=> "<div></div>"
```

But it always returns div tag without inner tag.

Why did happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to ruby scoping complete block passed to concat not `content_tag` separately. You can concat returned string using `+` operator. Try below code.

```
foo = ''
foo += content_tag :div do 
  label_tag 'bar' 
end
=> "<div><label for="bar">Bar</label></div>"
```

Comment: But `foo += content_tag :div do 
  label_tag('bar')
  content_tag(:span, 'baz')
end` did not work. Exactly second element did not be shown. Do you know why?